# VSCode Update 1.13.1 broke some keyboard bindings, How do I put them back?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

My VSCode just updated to 1.13.1 and now I can no longer use the Shift+Alt keyboard shortcut to initiate multi-line editing.  I was using this feature regularly - until it just broke with the 1.13.1 update.

At first I thought it was a keyboard or operating system fault.  However, I can still use those shortcut keys in Visual Studio 2017 side by side with VSCode.  It works in Visual Studio 2017 and does not work any more in VSCode.  I also tried in both Windows 10 and Windows 7.

How do I restore the VSCode keyboard bindings to their Visual Studio equivalents?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can add to your VSCode plugins the "[Visual Studio Keymap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vs-keybindings)" one:

> This extension ports popular Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts to Visual Studio Code.
>   **After installing the extension and restarting VS Code your favorite keyboard shortcuts from Visual Studio are now available**.

You can see the keyboard shortcuts in [`rebornix/vscode-vs-keybindings/package.json`](https://github.com/rebornix/vscode-vs-keybindings/blob/ea454517d7824733118a334ddc50faff7dbc2fb4/package.json#L26).